# Could not complete Activation Matlab

Tags: permissions, matlab, license

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on 64-bits. I am tryint to install Matlab R2014b. I followed these steps, based on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB) tutorial:

1. Mounted the .iso file
2. `cd /media/username/MATHWORKS_R2014B`
3. `sudo ./install (installed in /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b)`
4. `sudo apt-get install matlab-support`
5. `cd ~ sudo chown username -R ~/.matlab`

During step 4 the window which required activation appeared several times and when I had to give the usrrname the default was always root and I never changed that, but when I try to run it, the activation window appears again but this time with username instead of root and it gives me the following error:

`Could not complete Activation because the License File could not be written to disk.  You might not have write permission on the License File or the folder. /home/username/.matlab/R2014b_licenses/license_username_836966_R2014b.lic  See your System Administrator for assistance. The specific error message text is: /home/username/.matlab/R2014b_licenses/license_username_836966_R2014b.lic (No such file or directory).`

I googled this error and after some results I performed the following steps:

- `cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64`
  `sudo ./activate_matlab.sh`
- `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/licenses`
  `sudo chmod a+rw /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/licenses`

But still the same thing happens. And the problem is that in the `./matlab` folder I don't have the license file they are asking me for. And when I try to download it from the MathWorks account I can only save it as `licence.lic` which is different than the name they are asking me for and which cannot be saved in the `/usr/local/MATLAB/R20194b` folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you copy the necessary files from /root/.matlab to ~/.matlab of the user that should be using it?

Comment: @Fabby: what necessary files are you talking about? And the only .matlab folder I have is in /home/username.

Comment: OK, more info needed if you need detailed instructions: What was the username you used to install?  What is the username you use to run?

Comment: When I installed it I used root because that was the default, but when I try to run it, I get an activation window which has by default my current username. Tha same which appears in the file about which I get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you have two users: one called "root" (**big** no-no, but anyway, that's what you have) and one called "username"…

Then the command is

```
cp /root/.matlab/* /home/username/.matlab/
```

Comment: Actually, my user `username` has root privileges. So I should have changed the username in the Matlab installation to `username`, right? Instead of the user called root which was given by default.

Comment: In short: Yes!  :)

Answer (score 0):

For those installing higher versions of matlab. The

```
./activate_matlab.sh
```

is rather located in the bin directory. So

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/
```

Then

```
sudo ./activate_matlab.sh./
```

Should do the magic.